# Error message with robust regression in R

Tags: r, regression, robust, error-message

Whenever I run a robust regression model in R with `rlm` and with either M or MM methods, I get the following error message:

> Error: 'lqs' failed: all the samples were singular

I am not sure what it means and what I can do to bypass this error.

Comment: Questions about error messages from software are usually off-topic on CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), but are often on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). This 1 may be on-topic here, depending on whether the error has to do w/ understanding rob reg or R, but it would definitely be off-topic on SO, b/c it lacks a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). Moreover, we can't help you here w/o 1 either, b/c it's impossible to tell what's going on. Can you add a sample of data & code that reproduces this?

Comment: Wherever you post this you're likely to be asked for a small example that reproduces your problem that can be pasted into R. Can you make a really small data set that has the same message and show the code yo uused?